# initialize two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to initialize below map as 2D array but somehow I am not able to understand how can I initialize below map in 2D array. Somehow from the graph it is looking pretty confusing. Below is the graph:

[image]

Is this the right way to do it?

```
byte graph[][] = { { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, }, { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
```

Comment: `Initialize map as array...` What does that mean?

Comment: Code is fine, unless you want to initialize the graph from file, database, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's confusing about:

```
byte graph[][] = { 
    { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
    { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 
    { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
    { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
```

?

Probably the most flexible way to initialize and array like this is to store the data in a text file, something like so:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

And then read in the data, and initializing your array from the data. This allows you to more easily change the data without having to change your program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; as long as it compiles, it is "correct".
There are other ways to initialize this array but I am not really sure why this is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Create new 2-dimensional array.
int[][] values = new int[6][8];

// Assign elements within it.
values[0][3] = 1;
values[1][2] = 1;
values[1][3] = 1;
values[3][4] = 1;
values[3][5] = 1;
values[3][6] = 1;
values[4][0] = 1;
values[4][1] = 1;
values[5][2] = 1;
// Loop over top-level arrays.
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    // Loop and display sub-arrays.
    int[] sub = values[i];
    for (int x = 0; x < sub.length; x++) {
    System.out.print(sub[x] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```